# How can I reset the chapter number from zero with memoir?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm working with `memoir` class, the first chapter was numbering (chapter 1) but I would like numbering it from zero... how can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Related Question: [Getting section numbering to start at 0](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107470/getting-section-numbering-to-start-at-0)

Answer (score 13):

Adding `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}` seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Zero}
    \chapter{Chapter One}
\end{document}
```