# Start counting the chapter at 17

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reset the chapter number from zero with memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50344/how-can-i-reset-the-chapter-number-from-zero-with-memoir)

Is it possible that the first time I use `\chapter{}` it starts at 17 instead of 1? There must be a way but I can't find one.

Comment: A chapter always starts with `1` not `0`.

Comment: I'd say a duplicate: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50344/7417](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50344/7417)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\setcounter{chapter}{16}
\chapter{...}
```