# Getting section numbering to start at 0

Tags: sectioning, numbering

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}    
    \newpage

    \section{Preface} %want section number to be 0
    \thispagestyle{empty}    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage

    \section{Start From Here}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{And So On...}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \end{document}
```

> How do I get *section* numbering to start at 0?

**Edit:** I know I can do `\section*{Preface}`, but that removes it from the ToC, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Use `\section*{Preface} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}`.

Comment: If you *really* want a 0 section, add this to the preamble: `\setcounter{section}{-1}`; otherwise, do as Harish has suggested.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I have `\thispagestyle{empty}` because I want to clear out the header and footer, but I want to include a roman numeral on the preface. Is this possible?

Comment: @AlanH sure; please give me some minutes.

Comment: @AlanH Your wish with the pagenumbering is a separate question …

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I started a new post for my quesiton

Comment: @AlanH yes, it's better. Also, please include in that question the headers you are using and how you are using them.

Comment: Related Question: [How can I reset the chapter number from zero with memoir?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50344/how-can-i-reset-the-chapter-number-from-zero-with-memoir/)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Just insert `\setcounter{section}{-1}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Preface} %want section number to be 0
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpage
\section{Start From Here}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{And So On...}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do I need to set the counter to -1, rather than 0?

Comment: The default is 0. Each chapter increments the number and is labelled with the incremented number. So -1 produces 0 as the first label.

Comment: this does not seem to  work in the book documentclass.

Comment: I learned this: Make sure you set the conter AFTER the \chapter command if you are doing everything with \input.