# How can I make sure that *all* counters start at 0?

Tags: counters

I am dogmatic, and I believe that 0 is the very zerost number. Naturally, I would like all my counters to start at 0. Page counters, section counters, subsection counters, theorems, definitions -- everything! -- if it counts, it starts at 0.

I know how I can make a section counter start at 0: [Getting section numbering to start at 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107470/getting-section-numbering-to-start-at-0)

But how do I efficiently satisfy my dogma without having to write many `\setcounter{<...>}`?

Comment: By default, a `\newcounter` command initalizes any counter with `0`. The package `totcount` does initialize total counters however with `-1`. If somebody did not make errors in the class/package setup, this should not be a real issue. If there's a proper `\newcounter{foo}[bar]` statement, the counters on the reset list are set to zero as soon as the driver counter is increased with `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: You are wrong, I believe. The page number is zero until you look at the first page, which of course has page number 1.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am having a bit of trouble understanding your comment. The `totcount` package initializes total counters with -1, and if I understand correctly, the "total counters" are an addition of that package to count up the number of items of a thing? If yes, then what is the relevance/connection of total counters to counters, especially given the original question?

Comment: @user89: Just in case you're using the `totcount` package.

Comment: The `page` counter starts at -1 because I set it to the list explicitly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\the\numexpr(#1)-1\relax} 
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}
\def\@Roman#1{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral\numexpr(#1)-1\relax @}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


    \section{Zero}
        \subsection{Zero.Zero}
            \subsubsection{Zero.Zero.Zero}

    \section{One}\label{ooo}
        \subsection{One.Zero}
            \subsubsection{One.Zero.Zero}\label{aaa}

    \section{Two}
        \subsection{Two.Zero}\label{bbb}
            \subsubsection{Two.Zero.Zero}


See sections \ref{ooo}, \ref{aaa} and \ref{bbb}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is this arcane magic? It works with page numbers too! It works with figures! It works with `amsmath` and `amsthm` things!

Comment: @user89 you said you wanted it to apply to all counters. (it just changes the counter print commands so a counter prints as one less than its value. )

Comment: David, yeah, it does exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: I've found a minor issue with this. The reference list is printed starting from zero, which is nice, but along the text, the citations aren't synced: for instance, what is listed as [2] in the bibliography is mentioned as [3] along the text.

Comment: @RenanMezabarba ref works, I added an example. If \cite doesn't I think your bibstyle is doing something wrong, you could ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\LoopResetCounters` from `xassoccnt` which sets all counters given in the comma-separated list to zero.

**See the update for grabbing all counters defined with `\newcounter` and put them on a list at the end of this answer!**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{figure}{17}

\thefigure

\LoopResetCounters{page,section,subsection,figure,equation,subsubsection,table}

\thefigure

\end{document}
```

**Update**

I've grabbed the comment by David Carlisle and exploited the `\cl@@ckpt` list in order to reset the all counters to `-1`, but omitted the `page` counter there!

In order to make the resetting list work, the `\@stpelt` list must be changed at all.

No additional package is needed at all!

This procedure does not influence the `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` counters since those are not defined with `\newcount`.

```
\documentclass{article}



\makeatletter
\newif\if@resetall
\@resetallfalse

\let\latex@newcounter\newcounter
\newcommand{\ResetAllCounters}[1][-1]{%
  \EnableResetAll
  \def\@elt##1{%
    \def\@tmp@@a{##1}
    \def\@tmp@@b{page}
    \ifx\@tmp@@a\@tmp@@b % Check if it is the page counter
    \setcounter{##1}{\z@}%
    \else
    \setcounter{##1}{#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \cl@@ckpt% Loop through the list of all counters defined with \newcounter
  \gdef\@@resetvalue{#1}% Store the reset value
}

% Redefine the reset stepper \@elt - list marker
\let\latex@@stpelt\@stpelt

\def\@stpelt#1{%
  \if@resetall%
  \global\csname c@#1\endcsname \numexpr\@@resetvalue-1\stepcounter{#1}
  \else
  \latex@@stpelt{#1}%
  \fi
}%

\newcommand{\DisableResetAll}{%
  \global\@resetallfalse
}

\newcommand{\EnableResetAll}{%
  \global\@resetalltrue%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}

\section{Foo}
\ResetAllCounters
\part{Foostuff}
\section{Foostuff}
\subsection{Foostuff subsection}
\subsubsection{Foostuff subsubsection}
\paragraph{Foostuff paragraph}
\subparagraph{Foostuff subparagraph}


\part{Foobar}
\section{Foobar}
\subsection{Foobar subsection}
\subsubsection{Foobar subsubsection}
\paragraph{Foobar paragraph}
\subparagraph{Foobar subparagraph}


\ResetAllCounters
\DisableResetAll

\part{Barstuff}
\section{Barstuff}
\subsection{Barstuff subsection}
\subsubsection{Barstuff subsubsection}
\paragraph{Barstuff paragraph}
\subparagraph{Barstuff subparagraph}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would have to populate the comma separated list manually though?

Comment: @user89: Yes, at the current state of the package. I did explicitly no changes to the `\newcounter` command (I am the author of `xassoccnt` by the way)

Comment: I noticed you're the author (I looked up the package)! Is there no way to change the default value at which counters are initialized to -1?

Comment: @user89: Why should they are be initialized to `-1` now? You asked for `0`. And see the update please

Comment: Sorry, I might be confusing myself. According to this answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107470/getting-section-numbering-to-start-at-0, if I want section numbering to start at $0$, I should initialize the counter at $-1$. That way, when it gets incremented during the zerost ("first") use, it will use the value $-1 + 1 = 0$. By default, the counters are initialized at $0$, so that at the first use, they are incremented so that $0 + 1 = 1$?

Comment: I just noticed your edits too, so I will try to read the latest and understand that; you may have already answered my question!

Comment: @user89: Either use `\LoopSetCounter{foo,foobar,section}{-1}` or change the `0` in my second answer!

Comment: Christian, thanks in advance for your patience here. I played around with the second example in your answer (one change I made was that I removed the repetition of `\blinddocument`, and I simply have `\showallcounters \resetallcounters \blinddocument` within the `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`), and set the counters initially to -1; however this only changes the page number counter, and not the section/subsection counter. Do you notice the same thing? We are getting very close though!

Comment: I included the edited version of your second example, which I am working with, in my original question, so that you can compare easily!

Comment: I'll take a look later on

Comment: latex already has a list of all defined counters, you don't need to redefine `\newcounter` to grab that see `\show\cl@@ckpt`

Comment: @user89: The main problem is not my code actually but your feature request -- the reset counter list sets the counters explicitly to `0` and not to `-1`. This can be changed, but I don't see an advantage in this at all

Comment: @user89: I've updated my answer, but I don't think that your request is really well...

Comment: And of course, you will get into troubles with counter formatters with `\alph` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I accepted David's answer above, because it cleanl does exactly what I want, everywhere!

Comment: @user89: Your decision then -- his solution changes the counter output stuff, not the counters itself.