# Convert all counters to base 6

Tags: counters

Is it possible to change the numeration base of LaTeX? Actually I am looking for base 6.

I would like this change to apply to all counters (TOC, pages, chapters..).
I found this topic [How can I make sure that *all* counters start at 0?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325340/how-can-i-make-sure-that-all-counters-start-at-0)
 which is almost exactly what I want but I have not a base 10 to base 6 function.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\BASEVI\relax} 
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral\BASEVI\relax}
\def\@Roman#1{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral\BASEVI\relax @}
\makeatother
```

`BASEVI` is just a placeholder.

To know more about the seximal system: [seximal.net](https://seximal.net).

Comment: What would base 6 Roman be? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right, it is just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one liner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:cpn {@arabic} #1 { \int_to_base:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\textheight}{2.5cm} % to keep the image small

\begin{document}

\newcounter{test}

\loop\ifnum\value{test}<100
  \arabic{test}%
  \stepcounter{test}%
  \space
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Every counter that's defined to use `\arabic` will print in base six, including `page`.

[image]

Beware: this will break all macros that abuse `\the<counter>` for obtaining the decimal representation of the counter instead of relying on its abstract value.

Better defining a suitable representation and choosing it for representing the counters you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \basesix_print:N #1 { \int_to_base:nn { #1 } { 6 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \basesix_print:N {c}
\cs_new:Npn \basesix_start:n #1 { \basesix_print:c {c@#1} }
% user interface
\cs_new_eq:NN \basesix \basesix_start:n
% to keep \pagenumbering{basesix} happpy
\cs_new_eq:cN {@basesix} \basesix_print:N
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\textheight}{2.5cm} % to keep the image small
\pagenumbering{basesix}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{6}

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\basesix{test}}

\loop\ifnum\value{test}<100
  \thetest
  \stepcounter{test}%
  \space
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\SIX#1{\expandafter\int_to_base:nn\csname c@#1\endcsname6}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand\thesection{\SIX{section}}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\SIX{enumi}}
\begin{document}

\section{aa}

\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\end{enumerate}

\section{zzz}
zz
\section{zzz}
zz
\section{zzz}
zz
\section{zzz}
zz
\section{zzz}
zz
\section{zzz}
zz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your knowledge of `expl3` is astonishing!

Comment: @egreg Buono come il mio italiano

Comment: Exactly so. :-)